# convert ico to png formatter in vue laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to convert ico format file to png format

```
  $media_url ="https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/images/logos/favicons/v1/favicon.ico"
  $filePath = public_path('media_downloads').'/pnff.png';
  file_put_contents($filePath, file_get_contents($media_url));
             
  $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
  $res = $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($img), 'public');
  $downloadUrl = \Storage::disk('s3')->url($filePath);
```

i got s3 url but the file is not opening i think it is corrupted how can i change the image content type while saving to a folder also in s3

Comment: Non of this code is related to converting a image from ico to png? So please amend your title to be relevant to the issue you are asking about

Comment: @RiggsFolly iam putting content to the relevant path with png file name isn't it okay?

Comment: When you say “convert”, do you just mean “rename”?

Comment: You're just renaming the file, you'r not actually converting it. That takes a few more steps.

Comment: @ChrisHaas  no i wanna convert i used intervention package but it doesnt take ico format  how can i convert to png ? can u pls guide me on this

Comment: @aynber wht are the steps? pl share ur knowledge

Comment: From the [documentation](https://image.intervention.io/v2/api/save), it looks like you call `Image::make()` followed by `save()`, which should work for those two formats as long as [Imagick](https://image.intervention.io/v2/introduction/formats) is installed. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas i tried make call but i got `Unable to init from given binary data` error and i didnt install Imagick

Comment: I don't know that it's possible without Imagick. There's no native function to deal with ico files

Comment: @aynber is laravel supports imagick as composer package ?

Comment: It's [part software](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) and part [PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), so it's at a higher level than Laravel.

Comment: [There are a lot of questions on SO about converting ICO to PNG](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+php+convert+ico+to+png), but I don't think there's one exact answer

Comment: @aynber thanks for your time and effort.. i will look into these links and get back to u .. once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have done ico to png convertion by using [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) Thanks @aynber @Chris Haas for the guidance

```
           use Imagick;


            $file = $media_url;
            $extension = pathinfo(parse_url($file, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename = 'linkedin_thumbnail' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $local_file_path = public_path('media_downloads') . '/' . $filename;
            $contents = file_get_contents($file);
            file_put_contents($local_file_path, $contents);
            $image = new Imagick();
            $image->readImage($local_file_path);
            $image->cropThumbnailImage(100,100);
            $image->setImageFormat("png");
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            $filePath2           = public_path('media_downloads').'/'.date('ymdhis').'.png';
            $image->writeImage( $filePath2 );
            $media_url = $filePath2;

            unlink($local_file_path);
            unlink($filePath2);
```